# Probability problem regarding limit theorems

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let's consider this problem:
We have a slot machine that generates a number $k$ with probability: $$P_k=\frac{2^{k-1}}{3^k},k\in \mathbb{N}$$
If the generated number is divisible by 3, the player gets $0$ points. If the remainder is $1$, the player gets 10 points and if the remainder is $2$, the player loses 10 points.
What is the probability that after a 1000 generated numbers the player has between 50 and 100 points?

What bothers me is how we can identify what type of distribution this is? If I'm guessing right, this might be a Binomial distribution. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Why do you think that it is a binomial distribution?

Comment: @Phira Cause this reminds me of a problem of probability of k realisations in n tries.

Comment: You need to find the probability that it's a multiple of 3, +1, +2 and then work it out from there. Honestly, I would use some kind of simulation here.

Comment: @A6EE Where do you see the $n$? And shouldn't there be a binomial coefficient?

Comment: @Phira, $n$ is 1000.

Comment: @A6EE Well, it isn't a binomial distribution and you should not guess without looking up the formula. In addition, it is not needed to know the name of the distribution to answer the question. First question: What is the probability to get a number divisible by $3$ in a single try?

Comment: @Phira It's $1/3$.

Comment: @A6EE Why?.......

Comment: @Phira Because there are 3 possibilities and the probability of getting each one is the same. That is if you're talking in general case (randomly picking numbers from $\mathbb{N}$). I'm not sure what the probability is if the probability of getting a number $k$ is as given.

Comment: @A6EE Equal probability is *not* the general case. And yes, you need to use the given probability by summing all possible cases.

Comment: FYI, the exercise most probably asks you to invoke some classical limit theorem from probability theory. As such, the answers below do not even start to scratch the surface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incomplete sketch:

If we assume $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \dots\}$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^k=\dfrac{1}{2}[(2/3)+(2/3)^2+\cdots]=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot3=1\text{.}$$
The function$$P_k=\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^k\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}=\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2}{3}=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}$$
for $k = 1, 2, \dots$ corresponds to the probability mass function of a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) (in the "trials" form) with $p = \dfrac{1}{3}$. I will use $\text{Geom}(1/3)$ to denote this distribution.

Let $X_1, \dots, X_{1000} \sim \text{Geom}(1/3)$. Define
$$Y_i=\begin{cases}
0, & X_i \equiv0\mod 3 \\
10, & X_i \equiv 1 \mod 3 \\
-10, & X_i \equiv 2 \mod 3\text{,}
\end{cases}\qquad i = 1, \dots, 1000\text{.}$$
Find the probability mass function of $Y_i$, and what you're essentially looking for is 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(50\leq\sum_{i=1}^{1000}Y_i\leq100 \right)\text{.}$$

Comment: For the second possible support note that the sum equals $1/2\times 2/3\times 3$

Comment: @FoobazJohn Thanks. I've corrected the typo.

Comment: How do you suggest to use the elements your answer explains, to actually solve the question?

Answer (score 1):

Encode using probability generating functions. Let $X_i$ be the score of the $i$th round (where $X_i=0, 10, -10$ with probability one). Put $X=\sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_i$. Suppose that the $X_i$ are independent and note the $X_i$ are identically distributed. Further
$$
\sum_{k}P(X_1=k)t^k=Et^{X_1}=\frac{4}{19}t^0+\frac{9}{19}t^{10}+\frac{6}{19}t^{-10}=t^{-10}\left(
\frac{4}{19}t^{10}+\frac{9}{19}t^{20}+\frac{6}{19}
\right)\tag{0}
$$ 
since
$$
P(X_1=0)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3j}=\frac{4}{19};
\quad P(X_1=10)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3j+1}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{27}{19}=\frac{9}{19} 
$$
and
$$
\quad P(X_1=-10)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3j+2}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{4}{9}\times\frac{27}{21}=\frac{6}{19} .
$$
Because the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed it follows at once that
$$
\sum_{k}P(X=k)t^k=Et^{X}=(Et^{X_1})^{1000}=t^{-10^4}\left(
\frac{4}{19}t^{10}+\frac{9}{19}t^{20}+\frac{6}{19}\right)^{1000}
$$
We want
$$
\sum_{k=50}^{100}P(X=k)=\sum_{k=50}^{100}[t^{k+10^4}]\left(
\frac{4}{19}t^{10}+\frac{9}{19}t^{20}+\frac{6}{19}\right)^{1000}\tag{1}
$$
where $[t^m]$ extracts the coefficient of $t^m$ in the polynomial. Presumably the sum in (1) can be computed using a computer algebra system.